# Объявление глобального массива

Tags: php, массивы

```
foreach ($primeniaemost as $primkol) {
$kolmod[$i][$primkol] = array($primkol=>$kolel2);
}
$asda  = $kolmod;
```

Вот заполняю массив, в этом файле шаблона компонента каталога в битриксе $GLOBALS['asda'] работает, а другом не работает. Почему? это же глобальная область видимости. Какие варианаты? :D По всякому пробовал и global и во всех комбинациях :D

Comment: "Нет времени объяснять, разбирайтесь сами".

Answer (score 0):

$GLOBALS PHP
$GLOBALS - супер глобальная переменная PHP, которая используется для доступа к глобальным переменным из любого места в PHP-скрипте (внутри функций или методах).

Все глобальные переменные PHP хранятся в массиве [index]. index содержит имя переменной.

В приведенном ниже примере показано, как использовать супер глобальную переменную $GLOBALS:
https://schoolsw3.com/php/showphp_demo_global_global.php